# NotesCLI 3.4 java exception

Tags: java, api, lotus-notes

Does anyone have any clue of what that exception might be?
Or at least any help guiding where I should look?

```
@laptop:~/Downloads/NotesCLI-3.4.0$ ./notescli.cmd --version
Lotus Notes Command Line Email Client v3.4.0
Copyright (C) 2002, 2010 by IBM Corporation.
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: lotus/domino/local/Session.cpp_object
    at lotus.domino.local.NotesBase.PropGetBool(Native Method)
    at lotus.domino.local.Session.isOnServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyInstance.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.versionInfo$2(./lib/notescli3/notescli3.py:56)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(./lib/notescli3/notescli3.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx1.f$0(:1)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx1.call_function()
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.eval(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.eval(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.BuiltinFunctions.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.run$8(./lib/notescli3/notescli3.py:159)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(./lib/notescli3/notescli3.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyObject._jcallexc(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyObject._jcall(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.proxies.__main__$NotesCLI3$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Which version of Notes are you using. We just got a similar error in our client code that talks to Notes. We have not gotten this error in 6.5.1 all the way up to 8.5.1. We did get this in 8.5.2 and am wondering if it has something to do with that version of Notes. We are still using the 6.5.1 API jar to talk to Notes and haven't had any issues with it until now.

Comment: We had an issue where some Java code which was relying on Notes.jar to  run and was working fine on our machines with all Notes versions going back to early versions of LN7. As soon as the client was upgraded to  LN8.5.2, the code started throwing an error with locating the "cpp_object". We're yet to find a workaround other than downgrade the client to LN8.5.1. If anyone has any pointers they would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. You use Notes.jar form different version of LN client.

Setup java class path to the same Notes.jar that your LN use.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/0/b121798f8adb411f8525784c00326709?OpenDocument) post in one of IBM's Notes community formus, it appears that there may be a bug in the isOnServer property in Notes and Domino version 8.5.2.  That property is clearly being referenced in your stacktrace just before the error.

So the first thing I would do is download and apply the Fix Packs that IBM has issued for 8.5.2, which can be found [here](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24028680) and see if they solve the problem for you.  You could also try upgrading to Notes 8.5.3, which you'll need to get through your normal software distribution channel.

If that doesn't help, then your best course of action would probably be to downgrade to 8.5.1 and if *that* fixes the problem then you could take two paths: call IBM support and report the problem in 8.5.2 to the Notes programability support team and see if they can provide a hotfix, and/or go to the OpenNTF [site](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Command%20Line%20EMail%20Client) for the Notes command line client project and post the information in the discussion area and see if the developer can provide you with a workaround that avoids the isOnServer call.  (Or you could download the source code, create the workaround yourself, and then post your code back to OpenNTF, along with an explanation!)